# Why does variadic template parameter pack keep same size if a simple type parameter is included to the right of parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, pack, variadic

In order to find the position of a type in a variadic template I implemented the following template:

```cpp
template <class T, class ...Params, class Based>
size_t derived_index(Based* a) {
  // show template instance and size of Params
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  std::cout << sizeof...(Params) << std::endl; 
  
  // verify is a is one of the polymorphic types 
  if (dynamic_cast<T*>(a) != nullptr)
    return 0;
  else 
    return 1u + derived_index<Params..., Based>(a);
}
```

in such a way **`Based`** template parameter can be deduced, for instances:

```cpp
struct Base { virtual void f() = 0; };
struct A: Base { void f() override {} };
struct B: Base { void f() override {} };
struct C: Base { void f() override {} };
struct D: Base { void f() override {} };

int main() {
  Base* a = new A;
  Base* c = new C;
  std::cout << " index: " << derived_index<A, B, D>(c) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I did another implementation that looks better because it detects if it was not found and return -1, so i needed to overload **`derived_index`**:

**UPDATED VERSION** This one works well deducing Based type.

```cpp
template <class Based>
int derived_index(Based* a) {
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  return -1;
}

template <class T, class ...Params, class Based>
int derived_index(Based* a) {
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
 
  if (dynamic_cast<T*>(a) != nullptr)
    return 0;
  else {
    auto&& index = derived_index<Params...>(a); 
    return  index >= 0 ? 1 + index: -1;
  }
}
```

In first version **`Params`** size keeps invariant, Does anybody know which is the reason? Is it standard?

Thanks

Comment: The rules are such that the parameter pack always consumes the longest possible sequence of types. Thus, `derived_index<Params..., Based>(a)` is interpreted as: `T` == first type in `Params`, `Params` == the rest of `Params` plus `Based`, and `Based` is deduced from `a`. You kinda expect the compiler to read your mind and deduce `Based` sometimes but not other times, but a typical compiler lacks mind-reading abilities.

Comment: **Your question is not clear.** You don't show your observation (output) from both versions neither what you would have expected. It is not clear to what **keeps invariant** refers. By taking an extra minute while writing the question to provide so useful data, you are likely to increase the chance of somewhat answering your question.

Comment: Asking if it is standard without telling which standard nor which compiler is not very helpful. **By the way Visual Studio give similar output** (compared to onlineGBD).

Comment: Hi Phil1970, i found the reason and it was not related to standard but also by the way it was coded, adding **Based** at end of this statement: `return 1u + derived_index<Params..., Based>(a);` keeps the feed of parameters constant (T is removed from parameter pack and Based is added keeping the size of parameter pack constant. This code does not require any additional overload because the if statement will be execute finally as true.

Comment: An issue wit this approach is that it won't identify if it was not found (return -1)